# Deserializing multi-dimensional array GSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I want to deserialize the following json data https://mtgox.com/code/data/getDepth.php. I keep getting an error. Below is my code.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();  
String json =  readHTTPS(new URL("https://mtgox.com/code/data/getDepth.php"));
AskBids askBids  = gson.fromJson(json, AskBids.class);
```

My AskBids class look like:

```
public class AskBids {

 private  String [] []   asks;
 private String [] []  bids;

 public AskBids(){}
}
```

The error is get is com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: "asks"

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON linked in the original question contains over 2,800 JSON tokens, element names and values.  Here is a small section of that example that maintains the exact same structure.

```
{
    "asks": [
        [
            18.22,
            15.362
        ],
        [
            25.4682,
            20
        ]
    ],
    "bids": [
        [
            18.06,
            50
        ],
        [
            18.0099,
            32.64
        ]
    ]
}
```

That said, I copy-pasted the deserialization code from the original question, using both the original JSON and the shorter version I pasted above, and the code ran without error as expected.

Based on the error message `Expecting object found: "asks"`, I suspect that the `readHTTPS(URL)` method is not returning the correct result, in that it is not including the opening `{` of the JSON.  If this is the problem, but for some reason `readHTTPS(URL)` cannot be fixed, you could always "fix" its output by just concatenating the missing character(s).